# как принять значение из chekbox?

Tags: javascript, html

пытаюсь создать форму регистрации и там требуется принять соглашение , и мне нужно чтобы checkbox передавал значения true/false. Как это реализовать в чистом js?

Comment: `checkboxId.matches(':checked')` вернет boolean

Comment: не получается почему то

Comment: let checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox'); if(checkbox.matches('checked') != true)

Comment: @HLEBHLEB Куда "передавал"?

Comment: @HLEBHLEB Вы не видите, чем Ваш код отличается от того, что Вам дали?

Comment: я исправил , но не работает

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!checkbox.checked) {
  ...
}
```

```js
function getCheckboxState() {
  console.log(
    document.getElementById("checkbox").checked,
    checkbox.matches(':checked')
  );
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<br/>
<button onclick="getCheckboxState()">Get Checkbox State</button>
```

Comment: ваш код я понял сразу, а в что тут не так checkboxId.matches(':checked') ?

Comment: не у меня браузер ругается, считает  checkbox.matches(':checked') ошибкой